# How to Copy Messages backup of from one HornnetQ server to another Server?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, message-queue, hornetq

I have Hornet Queue message backup containing around 60 million messages from one of the server and i am trying to copy that backup to another server's HornetQ, But after copying backup to another server when i check the queues in Jconsole it shows 0 messages in that queue.

I copied paging and bindings folder from server1 to server 2.

Is there any special way to do that or i am missing something?

Regards,
Simer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must copy each of the 4 folders from one broker to another (i.e. large-messages, journal, bindings, & paging).  Aside from that you can start both brokers and use a bridge to move messages between them.

Comment: Thanks @Justin it works, I did the same already as the answer came late after so many days :), But it will be helpful for others.